# Python: BadZipFile even though zip is fine

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, zip

I have these two functions. The first one decrypts a zip file and unzips it in a temporary dir. The second one re-zips, re-encrypts and copies the file back to the original directory. They are chained together in the program (the file is decrypted when the program is run, and then encrypted again right before it exits)

```
def unzip_instance_to_temp(self):
    #Get PS file, copy to temp folder, unzip and delete original (the one that was unzipped, not the one in instances)
    from shutil import copy #used to copy zip file
    os.chdir('instances')
    try:
        copy(program_Config.instance_filename, PS_TEMPORARY_DIR) #PS_TEMPORARY_DIR is the path of the temporary directory
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise PSError('INSTANCE FILE (AS WRITTEN IN CONFIG) DOES NOT EXIST')
    os.chdir(PS_TEMPORARY_DIR)
    try:
        PSUtils_MAIN.unzip(program_Config.instance_filename_zipversion, '')
    except (zipfile.BadZipFile, FileNotFoundError): #BadZipFile is raised if it cannot be opened (probably encrypted, but keeps unencrypted ones from being put through)
        with open(program_Config.instance_filename, 'rb') as in_file, open(program_Config.instance_filename_zipversion, 'wb') as out_file:
            PSUtils_MAIN.decrypt(in_file, out_file, instance_encryption_key) #instance_encryption_key is a global (it is used across the program)
        try:
            PSUtils_MAIN.unzip(program_Config.instance_filename_zipversion, '')
        except zipfile.BadZipFile: #BadZipFile is raised if it cannot be opened (incorrect encryption key or corrupt file)
            raise PS_INSTANCE_ERROR('UNABLE TO DECODE INSTANCE (WRONG SECURITY KEY OR CORRUPT FILE)')
    os.remove(program_Config.instance_filename) #original encrypted file is deleted
    os.remove(program_Config.instance_filename_zipversion) #original zip is deleted
    #only files left in the temporary dir are the contents of the original zip

def rezip_instance(self):
    #Rezip contents of temporary dir, encrypt, copy back to original dir, delete temporary
    from shutil import rmtree, copy
    os.chdir('..')
    PSUtils_MAIN.zip(PS_TEMPORARY_DIR, program_Config.instance_filename.rstrip('.ps'))
    with open(program_Config.instance_filename_zipversion, 'rb') as in_file, open(program_Config.instance_filename, 'wb') as out_file:
        PSUtils_MAIN.encrypt(in_file, out_file, instance_encryption_key)
    copy(program_Config.instance_filename, program_Config.instances_path)
    os.chdir(program_Config.instances_path)
```

When using a new file, both of these work fine. The file gets encrypted and decrypted properly. The second time around however, I always get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\PySec\CurrentVersion\ps.py", line 670, in     unzip_instance_to_temp
    PSUtils_MAIN.unzip(program_Config.instance_filename_zipversion, '')
  File "E:\Projects\PySec\CurrentVersion\ps.py", line 504, in unzip
    zf.extract(member, path)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1228, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1290, in _extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1154, in open
    raise BadZipFile("Truncated file header")
zipfile.BadZipFile: Truncated file header
```

which then trips the function's error handler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\PySec\CurrentVersion\ps.py", line 972, in execute
    core = PSCore()
  File "E:\Projects\PySec\CurrentVersion\ps.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.unzip_instance_to_temp()
  File "E:\Projects\PySec\CurrentVersion\ps.py", line 672, in unzip_instance_to_temp
    raise PS_INSTANCE_ERROR('UNABLE TO DECODE INSTANCE (WRONG SECURITY KEY OR CORRUPT FILE)')
PS_INSTANCE_ERROR: UNABLE TO DECODE INSTANCE (WRONG SECURITY KEY OR CORRUPT FILE)
```

If I pause the execution of the encryption function right before the files are removed, and try to open the zip file with 7zip, it works just fine. All the files inside are intact.
Here are my zip functions in case they help:

```
def zip(src, dst):
    #zip files in src directory to a zip with filename dst
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("%s.zip" % (dst), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for filename in files:
            absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
            zf.write(absname, arcname)
    zf.close()

def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
    #unzip a zipfile of source_filename to directory dest_dir
    #path traversal protected
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
        for member in zf.infolist():
            words = member.filename.split('/')
            path = dest_dir
            for word in words[:-1]:
                drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
                head, word = os.path.split(word)
                if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir, ''): continue
                path = os.path.join(path, word)
            zf.extract(member, path)
```

Any idea what may be causing the error?

EDIT: Also, since opening the archive with 7zip proves that it is ok, would it be possible to tell zipfile to continue despite the error?